# Make an sql value equal to another value from another table on insert

Tags: mysql, sql

basically I have these both tables.

[image]

What I want to do is upon **INSERTION** of content in the second table (table 2) I want its value at *NULL* to be filled with the id from table 1 **in which** the pairs formed by part1/part2 from table 1 and part1/part2 from table 2 remain the same (**please notice they can exchange between them**). What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you using php or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create a trigger on Insert like below

```
CREATE TRIGGER grabIdFromTable1
BEFORE INSERT ON table2
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.id = (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE part1 = NEW.part1
                                        AND part2 = NEW.part2
                );

END//
```

see this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6cbc3f/1/0)

Comment: hey @TinTran, I wrote "(please notice they can exchange between them)" therefore I had to do something like this 

`CREATE TRIGGER grabID
BEFORE INSERT ON table2
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.id= (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE ((id1 = NEW.id1
                                        AND id2 = NEW.id2) OR (id1 = NEW.id2AND id2 = NEW.id1))
                );

END//`

but for some reason it points out a syntax error. Any idea why?

Comment: so you figured it out! great! wait syntax error? you need a space between NEW.id2AND

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: where are you running this CREATE TRIGGER command? You might need to say `DELIMITER //` before this CREATE TRIGGER command and then `DELIMITER ;` after this CREATE TRIGGER command.

Comment: php my admin in the SQL tab referred to table2

Comment: did you add a space in between the `NEW.id2AND` so that it's `NEW.id2 AND`? try `DELIMITER // CREATE TRIGGER grabID BEFORE INSERT ON table2 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SET NEW.id= (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE ((id1 = NEW.id1 AND id2 = NEW.id2) OR (id1 = NEW.id2 AND id2 = NEW.id1)) ); END// DELIMITER ;`

Comment: I tried that, it didn't report any error back but also didn't show any message confirmation... how can I check if the trigger was created in phpmyadmin without adding rows?

Comment: i  am not sure I would just try adding a row and then delete it after

Comment: It isn't adding more rows any longer :(

Comment: try `SHOW TRIGGERS LIKE 'table2'`

Comment: what isn't adding more rows? like you can't add rows to table2 anymore?

Comment: Now the addition of rows is working, but SHOW TRIGGERS LIKE 'table2' returned nothing

Comment: does it set the id like you wanted it to for table2? I have never used `SHOW TRIGGERS LIKE 'tablename'` before so i am not sure sure if it ran you should have that trigger.

Comment: SHOW TRIGGERS also didn't work and the id is not being set correctly... The error displayed without **DELIMITER** is a 1064 on this `CREATE TRIGGER getID BEFORE INSERT ON table2 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SET NEW.id= (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE ((id1 = NEW.id1 AND id2 = NEW.id2) OR (id1 = NEW.id2 AND id2 = NEW.id1 )) );`

Comment: try `DELIMITER //` then a newline the `CREATE TRIGGER ...` then a new line then `DELIMITER ;`

Comment: I did it! There was a problem with the query and the query delimiter option (it was ';' and I put it '//')! Thank you so much for your precious help and time!!! :D

Comment: yeh! do you have a site that hosts your app? which site do you use. I use 000webhost free account and they don't even allow me to create triggers.

Comment: I've used 000webhost before, but after a certain time I moved on to practicing on a local server via localhost :p